# File parsing and persistence in akka http

Tags: xml, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, akka-stream, akka-http

I need to make a server based on akka http that receives xml files and persists them into S3, the same file is parsed and its data sent to elasticsearch. It's my first time working with these technologies so I noticed that there are alpakka connectors available for elasticsearch and S3. Since these aren't large xml files I wonder if handling all these steps through akka stream flows is worth it? I am thinking of either doing this or loading the files to memory with a toStrict, parsing them and then persisting not necessarily with alpakka connectors.

What I need is some advice about how to think of this and when to think about using streaming connector for example for elasticsearch or just a simple client like elastic4s.

I hope I was clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer whether or not an `akka-stream` solution is "worth it" without knowing how to measure the cost & benefits.  But the amount of code for a stream solution is equivalent to a `toStrict` solution.

A `Route` can get the `entity` as a stream and then use a [`BroadcastHub`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-dynamic.html#using-the-broadcasthub) to send the data to two different sinks:

```
val route : Route = extractDataBytes { data =>
  val runnableGraph = data.toMat(BroadcastHub.sink(bufferSize = 256))(Keep.right)

  val s3Sink : Sink[ByteString, Future[Done]] = ???

  val elasticSearchSink : Sink[ByteString, Future[Done]] = ???

  val fromData = runnableGraph.run()

  val s3Fut      = fromData.runWith(s3Sink)
  val elasticFut = fromData.runWith(elasticSearchSink)

  for {
    _ <- s3Fut
    _ <- elasticFut
  } yield complete(StatusCode.Ok)
}
```